# What is the keyboard shortcut for deleting selected rows?

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts

What is the keyboard shortcut for deleting selected rows?

Currently I select rows with shift+ up/down and click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> and click <kbd>r</kbd> and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Is there a single key combination which I can use for doing this at one press?

Answer (score 4):

This is actually **two step action** to delete rows in excel:

Step:1 Select the row to be deleted: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>
Step:2 Delete row: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Click on the number of the row to select the entire row and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>. There is no need for <kbd>r</kbd> when entire row is selected.

Comment: u mean right click on that?

Comment: Just left click on the number of the row  or shift + space shortcut for selecting row where your cursor is then Ctrl + -